# kafka docker python API does not recognizes the broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I have a kafka consumer in VSCode IDE (MS Windows) that works properly. I take the same python script in docker container, but the kafka broker is not recognized. I put them inside the same network; so networking is OK. What could be the problem?

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import time
while True:
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            'topic01',
            bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'], #this works
            auto_offset_reset='latest',
            enable_auto_commit=True,
            auto_commit_interval_ms = 5000,
            fetch_max_bytes = 128,
            max_poll_records = 100,
            value_deserializer = lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')
        )
        break
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(2)
        print('exception happenned\n')
        print(f"an error occurred: {e}")

for message in consumer:
    print(message.value)
```

Networking issue checked.
I expect that the python script consumes the messages as it consumes in windows environment. But inside docker container the kafka broker is not recognized.

Comment: `localhost` in a container means the container itself. You need to put in the name assigned to the Kafka container on the Docker network instead.

Comment: Thanks, so if the name of the Kafka broker is kafka, I should make the bootstrap_servers as 'kafka:9092'?  I tried this scenario, but it shows the same behavior. Look forward.